# Find entries that have a category selected from a category field within a matrix block

Tags: matrix, categories, relations

I've got a Section that uses a Matrix field, that has a block, that has a categories field in it.

I want to find all entries using this Matrix field, who has a categories field and has a certain category selected.

I'm looking at the Relations documentation and trying the following code, but perhaps i'm barking up the wrong tree here?

```
{% set cat = craft.categories.slug('print') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('projectsEntries').relatedTo({
sourceElement: cat,
field: 'contentBuilder.relatedCategories.content'
}) %}

{% for entry in entries %}

{{ entry.title }}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `targetElement: cat` instead of sourceElement – in my experience the *entries* are considered the source of the relation in cases like these, not the categories.

Edit: Also, the `field` parameter of the `relatedTo` method shouldn't include the Matrix field's block type, only the actual category field – i.e. `contentBuilder.content`, not `contentBuilder.relatedCategories.content`.

Comment: I added the actual field in the block type to the example. But, trying what you said doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Hm. There's no need to include/specify the block type in the `field` parameter, `contentBuilder.content` should do nicely if the latter is your actual category field. Did you try with both `targetElement` and `contentBuilder.content`?

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right, using contentBuilder.content works along with targetElement. Superb! Thanks Mats!!

Comment: Awesome! I edited the answer to include that detail, for reference.