# How to get entries that have a category selected from a category field within a matrix block?

Tags: craft3, categories

I've got a Section that uses a Matrix field, that has a block, that has a categories field in it.

I want to find all entries using this Matrix field, who has a categories field and has a certain category selected.

Tried the sloution given in the following URL, but no luck:
[[Find entries that have a category selected from a category field within a matrix block](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8463/find-entries-that-have-a-category-selected-from-a-category-field-within-a-matrix][1])

I have a category group faqCategory. Inside that 3 categories Transport Category (transport-category), Room Category (room-category) and Services Category (services-category).

I have Matrix custom field defined called faqList, which has Block Type FAQ, inside FAQ block 3 fields faqCat(Type of above faqCategory), Question(Type of Text) and Answer(Type of Text).

Another text field called pageTitle.

There is a Single Type section called faqsPage, which has entry Types pageTitle and faqList.

Based on the above provided solution for the original question I have programmed it as follows:

```
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('faqCategory') %}

    <b>{{ category.title }}</b></br>

    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('faqsPage').relatedTo({
        targetElement: category,
        field: 'faqList.faqCat'
    }) %}

    {% for entry in entries %}

        {{ entry.title }}</br>

    {% endfor %}

{% endnav %}
```

Following is the output:

Transport Category

FAQs Page

Room Category

FAQs Page

Services Category

FAQs Page

> Instead of proper entries it returns page itself. Please help.